# Why am i not able to use the getOwner() method of Reentrant class in subclass directly?

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, protected, reentrantlock

Im trying to use the getOwner method in the class that subclass the ReentractLock class,
I know outside the package, protected methods will be available to the subclass only.
So i expect the getOwner method to be available to my sublcass MyLock.
But im not able to use it.

1.

```
public class Mylock extends ReentrantLock { }
```

When i use `new Mylock().getOwner()`
I get error, getOwner is not defined.

2.

```
public class Mylock extends ReentrantLock {
 String getOwner() {  
 Thread t =  this.getOwner();  
 return t.getName();  
}}
```

Now when i use new `MyLock().getOwner()` it works.

My question is when i use `new MyLock().getOwner()` with first logic, why it shows method undefined, atleast i should get the thread object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#getOwner()) `ReentrantLock.getOwner()` is `protected`. When you override the method, you are giving it default access instead. For more information, read about the differences between `public`, `protected`, default, and `private` access levels.

Comment: Thats my question, it is protected, so it should be available to the subclass in outside the package. Here so MyLock class should have visibility to it. But y its not visible?

Comment: @Arasn The line of code `new MyLock().getOwner()` is not in a method of the subclass, so the call is not allowed. I suggest that you read more about how `protected` works. It sounds like you have a misunderstanding here that needs to be cleared up.